# Algorithm to detect a linear part of a data set

Tags: python, algorithm

I hope I'm in the right place to ask this but my problem is the following : I have a set of data (two lists x and y), I dont have much other information about this set (no function, or anything like this). My goal is to find the subset of this data that is linear (the part highlighted in yellow in the image below).

[image]

As you can see on the image after plotting the data we can see that it becomes linear for a while. and I want to detect that subset automatically. since I dont have the function behind it I'm really lost!!

Anyone has an idea on how this can be done ? an algorithm or a mathematical method I can implement ? (Im using python btw)

Comment: Does the incline need to be linear? (does the unknown function has to be y = ax + b)

Comment: Yes, the data set contains a subset that is linear and satisfies a function of type y = ax + b

Comment: You can look at something like [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) to extract a linear model of the region of interest (as long as the majority of points fall within it), then select the points that you would qualify as "inliers" with some reasonable threshold.

Comment: Is the section perfectly linear, or linear with some noise? Also, what if there are multiple linear segments?

Comment: Don’t you just wanted find where the second derivative of your data is 0 within some margin of error?

Answer (score 2):

You could start by determining the slope of two points by using their x and y values.

Say points 1 and 2 and the slope = 2. 
And then calculate the slope of points 2 and 3. 
If the slope of the latter is different than the former then you know it’s not linear.

Just do a for loop through the whole data set and compare the current value with the next value to get the slope.

```
from decimal import Decimal
def linear_equation(p1,p2):
    #points are arrays like p=(x,y)
    m=slope(p1,p2) #slope 
    c=(p2[1]-(m*p2[0])) #y-intercept of line
    return 'y='+str(m)+ 'x' +'+' +str(c)

def slope(p1,p2):
    return Decimal((p2[1]-p1[1]))/Decimal(p2[0]-p1[0])

points =[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[7,30],[8,35],[9,39]]


for p in range(0,len(points)-2):
    #if the slopes of points (a,b) and (b,c) are the same then print the equation
    #you could really omit the if statment if you just want to calculate the
    #equations for each set of points and do the comparasons later.
    #change the for condition to -1 instead of -2 if this is the case.
    if slope(points[p],points[p+1]) == slope(points[p+1],points[p+2]):
        print(str(lin_equ(points[p],points[p+1])))
    else:
        print("Non-Linear")
```

Output:

y=1x+0

Non-Linear

Non-Linear

y=1x+1

Non-Linear

Non-Linear

Non-Linear

Comment: But even if they have the same slope , that doesn't mean they're linear as well, because they can have different y-intercepts (parameter b in y = ax + b)

Comment: The graph provided isn’t linear, so you wouldn’t be able to fit it in slope intercept form. The Y-Intercept really is irrelevant in finding if something is linear. It just determines the starting point of a linear equation. Which yours is not(it had curves).You just need to loop through and compare the slopes of each line segment and the ones that match in succession are linear. @AnotherBrick